# Terminal servers, VM clone keep getting kernel-power 2008r2 crashing both servers

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, terminal-server, vmware-vcenter, server-crashes, clone

I'm desperate at the moment to get an answer to the following problem.

Als servers are managed in our VMWare-vcenter environment.

We've got 2 terminal servers, term01 and term01 and we also got a loadbalancer.

Some weeks ago we had a Cryptoware on our term02.
One terminal server was not functioning correctly anymore so we decided to get rid of it and make a clone by using the term01.

Anyhow, we made the clone and changed everything from term01 tot term02(Hostname etc.)

Now everytime people start to login into the term02 both servers crash. 
It was running over night and nothing happened but everytime at around 6:30 when people start to login both servers crash and keep rebooting.

When we disable the network card this doesn't happen, so it seems this is a network issue.

We already did a sysprep, sfc /scannow, checked our drivers, thoroughly looked through our event viewer. Just the standard Kernel-power error.
We tried everything I could find but nothing worked or even got us a clear answer.

I've searched many forums but haven't gotten any answers, I did find one article and the guy couldn't figure it out either so decided to build it from scratch.

So my hope is on you guys if you maybe got an answer to my problem?

Comment: `Some weeks ago we had a Cryptoware on our term02. One terminal server was not functioning correctly anymore so we decided to get rid of it and make a clone by using the term01` - Did you not have backups of these virtual machines?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Before me a guy from Finance did all the IT stuff and the TERM02 was not included in the backup.